# Use 'J' key to goto next match in Vrapper

Tags: eclipse

### Question

Is there a way to get <kbd>j</kbd> to move to the next result in the Eclipse auto-complete popup when using Vrapper?

### Rationale

When I use Eclipse auto completion <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, I would like to use the <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> keys to move to the next and previous match. I get so used to moving this way in Vrapper that it is a bit hard to switch tactics in the specific Eclipse situations that Vrapper does not control. The auto-complete popup is the most common of these situations for me.

### Possibilities

I see several possibilities for solving this:

1. Write a feature request for Vrapper to solve this (if it isn't solved already)
2. Create a key combination in Eclipse if the command for this is exposed
3. Create a key combination outside of Eclipse that sends a <kbd>↓</kbd>
4. Live with using the <kbd>↓</kbd> key like everyone else does
5. Perhaps there is a .vimrc trick such as mapping <kbd>j</kbd> to <kbd>↓</kbd>and Eclipse will capture that <kbd>↓</kbd>

Comment: Vrapper does not yet exist as a tag in StackOverflow. Would it make sense to add one? If so, I do not have enough credit to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this same question on github and got the following response which answers the question. I'm re-posting it here.

> We have an option :set contentassistmode which will enable Ctrl-n/Ctrl-p to go to next/previous match in the Ctrl-Space pop-up. You can then use :camap to remap  and  to j and k or any other key you want. I'm sorry but we don't have a solution for the quick-fix pop-up.
>
> See http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/?topic=configuration#vrapper

Link: https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/issues/648

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this until I find a better one is to use the following AutoHotkey script:

```
#j:: ; The # stands for the left win key
SendInput {Down}
return
#k::
SendInput {Up}
return
```

I'm not completely happy using the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> combination, but it seems to work fairly well for now.